# What's the correct version of this "product rule" is topology?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

An exercise asks me to do the following:

> $(x_1,\tau_1), (X_2,\tau_2)$ are two topological spaces. $A_i\in X_i, i=1,2.$ Show that $\partial(A_1\times A_2)=(\partial A_1\times A_2)\cup(A_1\times \partial A_2)$, given that $X_1\times X_2$ has the product topology.

I think the result is wrong. I believe it should be $\partial(A_1\times A_2)=(\partial A_1\times \bar{A_2})\cup(\bar{A_1}\times \partial A_2)$, where bar denotes closure and $\partial$ denotes boundary.

Am I right?

Comment: Just as an example, take $X_i = \Bbb R$ and $A_i = (0,1)$. Then $\partial (A_1\times A_2)$ should be the boundary of the unit square, yet with the given definition the corners aren't included.

Comment: The answer to the linked question gave a proof of $\partial(A_1\times A_2)=(\partial A_1\times \bar{A_2})\cup(\bar{A_1}\times \partial A_2)$ (so this should be the correct product rule)